# Norm of cos in $L^2[-T,T]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, orthonormal

I am reading the book Applied Fourier Analysis by Tim Olson. There I got introduced the Fourier Series and we have derived the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ for the Fourier Series on $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. The author is now setting up to introduce orthonormal expansions.

I could recreate the norm of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ as follows:

For $\cos$
$$\begin{align}
 \lvert\lvert \cos \rvert\rvert  &= \sqrt{  \int _{-\pi}^\pi   \cos^2(t) \, dt} \\
  &= \sqrt{ 2\int _{0}^\pi   \cos^2(t) \, dt} \tag{$\cos$ even function}\\
  &= \sqrt{ 2\left[\frac{1}{2}(\cos(t)\sin(t) + t)\right]_{0}^\pi} \\
  &= \sqrt{ \cos(\pi)\sin(\pi) + \pi - (\cos(0)\sin(0)) } \,  \\
  &= \sqrt{ (-1)\cdot0 + \pi }  \\
  &= \sqrt{ \pi} \,  \\
\end{align}$$
For $\sin$
$$\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert \sin \rvert\rvert  &= \sqrt{ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^2(t) \, dt} \\
&= \sqrt{ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1 - \cos(2t)}{2} \, dt} \\
&= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi (1 - \cos(2t)) \, dt }\\
&= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left[t - \frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi }\\
&= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(\pi - (-\pi) - \frac{\sin(2\pi)}{2} + \frac{\sin(-2\pi)}{2}\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(2\pi \right) }\\
&=\sqrt{  \pi}
\end{align}$$

When continuing to read the author uses $\sqrt{T}$as normalization for $\sin$ and $\cos$ in $L^2[-T,T]$. I could recreate this for $\sin$ but I am stuck with $\cos$. My calculations are the following:
For $\sin$
$$\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert \sin \rvert\rvert &= \sqrt{ \int _{-T}^T  \lvert \sin(t) \rvert^2 \, dt }  \\
 &= \sqrt{ \int _{-T}^T \sin^2(t) \, dt  } \\
 &= \sqrt{ \int_{-T}^T \frac{1 - \cos(2t)}{2} \, dt }\\
 &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \int_{-T}^T 1-\cos(2t) \, dt } \\
 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left[t-\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right]_{-T}^T  } \\
 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(T-\frac{\sin(2T)}{2} - \left( -T-\frac{\sin(-2T)}{2} \right)\right)  }\\
 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(T - \frac{\sin(2T)}{2}  + T + \frac{\sin(2T)}{2} \right)  } \\
 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(2T\right)  } \\
 &= \sqrt{ T  } \\
\end{align}$$

For $\cos$
$$\begin{align}
 \lvert\lvert \cos \rvert\rvert &= \sqrt{ \int _{-T}^T \lvert \cos(t) \rvert^2 \, dt  } \\
  &= \sqrt{ \int _{-T}^T \cos^2(t) \, dt  } \\
  &= \sqrt{ 2\int _{0}^T \cos^2(t) \, dt  }\\ 
  &= \sqrt{ 2\left[\frac{1}{2}(\cos(t)\sin(t) + t)\right]_{0}^T } \\
  &= \sqrt{ \cos(T)\sin(T) + T } \\ 
\end{align}$$

First of all, I need some help with $\cos$, because this is not the expected result I have. Additionally the book will continue to work on $L^2[a,b]$. Is there any trick I need to keep in mind going on also to show the normalized versions in $L^2[a,b]$?

Also, if there are better books you can recommend, I am happy to take recommendations.

Comment: You should consider the identities connecting $cos^2(x)$ to $cos(2x)$. The latter is much nicer to integrate.

Comment: If you are speaking about $cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + cos(2x))$, I checked it and it resulted in quite the same expression

Comment: You could also make a change a variable in the integrals of $u=\pi/T t$, with $dt = T/ \pi du$.

Comment: You made a mistake computing the integral of $\sin^2(t)$ on $[-T,T]$. The calculation of the cosine integral is correct. You shouldn't expect to just get "T" in either case.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I can work this out with your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the subject is Fourier series you should probably compute the norm of the trigonometric polynomials which are periodic of period $P$. Your author uses the notation where the period is $P=2T$

This means you should consider the norm of the functions $\cos(\omega n x)$, $\sin(\omega n x)$ where $n$ is an integer and $\omega=2\pi/P=\pi/T$.

After a simple change of variable the computation is reduced to the case where the period is $2\pi$.

The trick to integrate is either use bisection formulae:

\begin{align}
\cos(y)^2 &= \frac{1+\cos(2y)}{2} \\
\sin(y)^2 &= \frac{1-\cos(2y)}{2} \, , \\
\end{align}

as you are doing, or integrate by parts.

Finally, Fourier series become much simpler in the complex case, where the orthonormal basis is simply $e^{ikx}/\sqrt{2\pi}$.